# Using SQLAlchemy, what is a good way to load related object that are were not eager loaded?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have this simple ORM:

```py
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__='foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    
    bar = relationship('Bar', uselist=False, uback_populates='foo')
    
class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__='bar'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'), index=True)
    foo = relationship('Foo', back_populates='bar')
```

At some point during the program I load a bunch of Foo object,

```py
f = session.query(Foo).all()
```

and now I would like the session to load their Bar attribute so that I can access it using the "dot". I would like if possible to have them loaded all at once. What is a clean way of doing it ?

I could do something like

```py
session.query(Bar).filter(Bar.foo_id.in_([x.id for x in f])).all()
```

but I think their must be a better way, because:

1. this would need to be split if the list is too long due to max size of a query
2. I don't really care about having those bars accessible, I just don't want sqlalchemy to emit queries every time I access the attribute with "dot"

Eager loading would be a solution but in some usage I will never need those bars so I'd rather not eager load them.

Comment: You really only have two ways of loading data, *eager* or *lazy*, how is SQLAlchemy supposed to know when you're loading a `Foo` whether you will or won't use its `bar` attibute ?

Comment: Instead of `session.query(Foo).all()` you could try `session.query(Foo).options(selectinload(Foo.bar)).all()`

Comment: @ljmc, Indeed SQLAlchemy cannot know in advance. That is why I don't mind doing it when needed. But I am really looking for a good way to load objects refered by relationship in a bulk way, given a list of parent objects. This might clarify. ultimately I have my foo in a pandas Series, say "se", and I do smght like se.foo.apply(lambda x: x.bar).
In this case, I don't want sqlalchemy to emit a query for each row.

Thank you very much for your help (and formating)

Comment: @GordThompson, I think this approach would still lead to the bar objects to be loaded whenver foos are loaded right ? In most use case that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Using `joinedload` is 1 query, using `selectinload` is 2 queries but can be simpler if you have other queries joining at the same time.

These are just one off queries and don't change the default loading strategy.

[relationship-loading-with-loader-options](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-with-loader-options)

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload
results = session.query(Foo).options(joinedload(Foo.bar)).all()

from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload
results = session.query(Foo).options(selectinload(Foo.bar)).all()
```

Comment: Doing this will load all Bar objects that have a parent Foo, what I want is really just to load the Bar object with parents in a list of already loaded Foo object, 'f' in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set lazy/eager loading using old style queries like shown by @ian-wilson, or new style [`select`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) query with a [loader option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-with-loader-options) which works if you are using [`pandas.read_sql_query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query).

See the following example:

**NB.** Without knowing how or why you load your foos into pandas, or what logic says "load bar for all these foos", I'm assuming it can be known at loading time, if OP provides more information I'll update this answer.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum, ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, joinedload, relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    bar = relationship("Bar", uselist=False, back_populates="foo")

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"), index=True)
    foo = relationship("Foo", back_populates="bar")

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", future=True, echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(bind=engine) as session:
    session.add_all([Foo(id=n, bar=Bar(id=n + 100)) for n in range(1, 10)])
    session.commit()

lazy_df = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql=select(Foo),
    con=engine.connect(),
)
# SELECT foo.id

eager_df = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql=select(Foo).options(joinedload(Foo.bar)),
    con=engine.connect(),
)
# SELECT foo.id, bar_1.id AS id_1, bar_1.foo_id
# FROM foo LEFT OUTER JOIN bar AS bar_1 ON foo.id = bar_1.foo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

With models

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    name = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

and sample data

```py
with Session(engine) as sess:
    sess.add_all(
        [
            Parent(
                id=1,
                name="Homer",
                children=[Child(name="Bart"), Child(name="Lisa")],
            ),
            Parent(
                id=2,
                name="Ned",
                children=[Child(name="Rod"), Child(name="Todd")],
            ),
            Parent(
                id=3,
                name="Skinner",
                children=[],
            ),
        ]
    )
    sess.commit()
```

you can re-load the objects in a list with `.options(selectinload(…))` like so:

```py
engine.echo = True
with Session(engine) as sess:
    print(">>> retrieve objects with (default) lazy-load")
    homer_and_ned = sess.scalars(select(Parent).where(Parent.id <= 2).order_by(Parent.id)).all()
    """
    SELECT parent.id, parent.name 
    FROM parent 
    WHERE parent.id <= ?
    ORDER BY parent.id
    [generated in 0.00029s] (2,)
    """
    homer = homer_and_ned[0]

    print(">>> refresh objects in list and eager-load children")
    parent_ids_to_refresh_with_children = [p.id for p in homer_and_ned]
    sess.scalars(
        select(Parent)
        .where(Parent.id.in_(parent_ids_to_refresh_with_children))
        .options(selectinload(Parent.children))
    ).all()
    """
    SELECT parent.id, parent.name 
    FROM parent 
    WHERE parent.id IN (?, ?)
    [generated in 0.00113s] (1, 2)
    SELECT child.parent_id AS child_parent_id, child.id AS child_id, child.name AS child_name 
    FROM child 
    WHERE child.parent_id IN (?, ?)
    [generated in 0.00036s] (1, 2)
    """
    print(">>> accessing homer.children ...")
    print(homer.children)
    """
    -- (no SQL emitted)
    """
```